# Get the nth distinct column value ordered by another column

Tags: mysql, group-by, order-by, distinct

I want to get the row with the *n*th distinct value in a column, as ordered by another column.

In more real terms, I want the 1000th distinct `email_address` as ordered by `created_at`, and the `email_address` column does not have a unique constraint.

I believe I have done this correctly with the following query:

```sql
SELECT `email_address`
    FROM footable
    GROUP BY `email_address`
    ORDER BY `created_at` ASC
    LIMIT 1
    OFFSET 1000
```

But I am not totally confident that is giving me the right value.

**Is the above query correct for this purpose? If not, how should I solve this?**

Comment: Show us an example with 10-20 rows (and how to get, say the 5th "distinct" value). It's not clear otherwise what you mean with "distinct but ordered by another column".

Comment: As for the query it is not even correct SQL. It's a pity that MySQL allows it and you should not use it for anything.

Comment: @ypercube how should it be corrected?

Comment: Please explain what you mean with "distinct". If for example the first (ordered by created_at) 500 emails are identical, you would expect the query to return the 1500th row?

Comment: @ypercube yes exactly, if the remaining 1000 emails are all distinct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two changes:

- a major one: Using an non-aggregated column in a `GROUP BY` query will yield unpredictable result - it's a pity that default setting s in MySQL allow this type of query, and good that it is corrected in 5.7 version.
  The problem with your query is that an email address can appear in many rows - **with many different `created_at` values** - and the question is: Which of these different values will MySQL use for the `ORDER BY`? The answer is any one of the them. It's usually the first it will find but "first" here can mean different things, depending on the execution plans and available indexes. So, the results will not be determinate and may change from one execution to another.
  You can use `MIN(created_at)` instead for the `ORDER BY` and the issue  is solved.
- a minor one: `OFFSET x` means *"skip x rows"*. Replace `1000` with `OFFSET 999`:

  ```
  SELECT email_address
      FROM footable
      GROUP BY email_address
      ORDER BY MIN(created_at) ASC
      LIMIT 1
      OFFSET 999 ;
  ```

Comment: Thanks. Does adding `MIN(created_at)` for the `ORDER BY` directly address the major issue you mention or is it a workaround? I'm not clear what the major issue actually is.

Comment: Yes, it addresses the major issue. I added some more explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can run those queries:

```
    SELECT 
      email_address
    FROM footable
    GROUP BY email_address
    ORDER BY created_at ASC
    LIMIT 0,1000;
```

---

```
    SELECT 
      DISTINCT email_address
    FROM footable
    ORDER BY created_at ASC
    LIMIT 0,1000;
```